# How do create DB collection in view?

Tags: module, magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I'm trying code

```
<?php $models = $this->getModel();  ?> ("getModel() is model slideshowdata")
        <?php if($models -> count() > 0 ): ?>
            <?php foreach($models as $model): ?>
                <?php   $objSlideshow = $this->_objectManager->get("Xanka\Slider\Model\Slideshow")->load($model->getId());?>
...
```

but not true. Any suggestion ?
I wana getModel slideshow with condition slideshow_id(slidehoswdata) aqua slidesshow_id(slideshow). so how make it ? I use

```
<?php   $objSlideshow = $this->_objectManager->get("Xanka\Slider\Model\Slideshow")->load($model->getId());?>
```

but wrong.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

First add method getCollection() to Block Class

```
<?php
namespace Xanka\Slider\Block\Adminhtml\SlideshowData;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{   

    protected $_slideshowDataFactory;
     protected $_coreRegistry = null;

     public function __construct(
         \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context, 
          \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Xanka\Slider\Model\Resource\SlideshowData\CollectionFactory $slideshowDataFactory,     
        array $data =[]     
    )
    {
        $this->_slideshowDataFactory = $slideshowDataFactory;
         $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }

     public function getModel(){
         $models = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('slideshowdata_index');
         return $models;
     }
   public function getCollection()
   {
      return $this->_slideshowDataFactory->create();
   }
}
```

second, use it in template

```
<?php $models = $block->getCollection(); ?>

<?php if($models->count() > 0 ): ?>
    <?php foreach($models as $model): ?>
      // implement your logic here
    <?php endforeach;?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: why do you need the `_prepareLayout` and `getModel` methods? The rest looks awesome :).

Comment: It's  *copypasta*  from previous @xanka question. I just add getCollection method.

Comment: @xanka. you don't need my help. KAndy already answered your question. it should work.

Comment: Thanks @KAndy but that's not what I want.

Comment: i want get collection B And get collection A by Id of B

Comment: @xanka. you can create method in block
function getModelById($id) {
    return $this->slideshowFactory->create()->load($id);
} 
where slideshowFactory is \Xanka\Slider\Model\Resource\SlideshowDataFactory

Answer (score 0):

In Block it will be

```
<?php
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Block;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;
    protected $_testmodel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Sugarcode\Test\Model\Test $testmodel,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_testmodel = $testmodel;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getAllData()
    {

        //$data = $this->_testmodel->load(1);
        $datas = $this->_testmodel->getCollection();
        return $datas;
    }


}
```

and in phtml i called

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$datas = $this->getAllData();
foreach($datas as $data){
    print_r($data->getData());
    echo '***************************************************************</br>';
}
?>
```

its working !!!